# Позиционирование шапки таблицы

Tags: html, firefox

В таблице требуется зафиксировать в начале `<thead>`, чтобы при прокрутке прокручивалось только `<body>`, т.е. примерно такая структура:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
  <table>
    <thead>
       ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       ...
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

`position: fixed` не катит, так как нужно чтоб относительно самой страницы шапка двигалась.
В IE к td и th сделано так:

```
top:expression(parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop)
```

нужно под Firefox, делать шапку отдельной таблицей нет возможности, на JQuery тоже, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: спасибо за достановку тегов, просто у меня они толи обрезались, то ли что)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
table thead,
table tbody {
  display: block;
}

table tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

table td {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>№</td>
      <td>ФИО</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Иванов</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Сидоров</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Петров</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Иванов</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Сидоров</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Петров</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Иванов</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Сидоров</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Петров</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```